# using SafeBEP20 for IBEP20

Tags: solidity, bsc

I created one token which is based on BEP20.
I am writing another smart contract, where I will be using this token, and want to perform some action like transfer, transferFrom, etc.

As I understand, there are newer methods available in (SafeBEP20) for these like `safeTransferFrom`, which handles error in a better way.

My query is: Can I use SafeBEP20 methods in my second contract on my token, although my original token does not have these methods defined?

Assuming I do something like below, and then try to use SafeBEP20 methods.

```
using SafeBEP20 for IBEP20;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems we can use SafeBEP20 methods even though token is BEP20 compliant.